# Bootstrap's tooltip part of HTML tag is not interpreted by GWT Project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am currently working at a GWT Project and want to use the Bootstraps tooltip in a very specific case:

**What is it about:**
Part of the program enables a user to enter an interface. This interface contains textboxes where he can enter text. After saving this text, it can be viewed from another page of the program.
What is **important**: the text which is entered by the user can be plain text, but also HTML which is then interpreted. So if the user wants to display a HTML list instead of doing something like this
- first item
- second item
- third item
he can just type

```
<ul><li>first item</li><li>second item</li><li>third item</li></ul>
```

instead of plain text.
This example works fine also style definitions work fine.

**What is the problem:**
If I want to use Bootstraps tooltip in the exact same interface and textboxes as described above it doesn't work.
If I enter the following to a textbox

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

the "**Hover over me**" is displayed as a link (in blue) and when hovering it gets underlined as expected.
But when holding the hover only the normal title "**Hooray!**" is displayed not the Bootstraps one.

I initialized the tooltip as described in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });
</script>
```

This script is located in the GWT's underlying HTML file.

**How is it processed:**
Internally in the GWT Project first gets the pure string from the textbox and this string is then used to create a HTML Widget (on the fly) which is then further shown at some other place as already mentioned.

**Note:**
I can not change the way the information is entered since it is crucial that the user has the freedom to enter information as described above.

**Why do I need this:**
In order to enable tooltips also for touch devices.

Is it possible that the tooltips are initialized at the wrong time?
What I mean is, the tooltips are initialized at the very beginning when opening the program. But to get to the part of the program where one can see the tooltips one must click through a couple of interfaces. Maybe the tooltips should be initialized only at the exact time when entering/loading the corresponding area?

**If anyone has an idea it would be a big help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - you need to initialize bootstrap tooltips after you add them to DOM structure.

In bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) you can read:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself**.

The script you have shown is called when the document is *ready*. It finds all elements that have parameter `data-toggle` set to `tooltip` value (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)). Then, for all such elements it calls bootstrap tooltip init function. If you add new tooltip it is not initialized automatically.

You can init new tooltips with this method:

```
private native void initTooltips() /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the problem. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve it by now: I tried adding your method as a static one in another class and from the same class where the corresponding widgets are created..it doesn't work for me. I am really a noob (yet) in terms of jQuery, is there anything else I have to take into account? I also tried using $wnd.$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); instead, also doesn't work. I called the method AFTER the HTML widget is created and its content given...

Comment: Well, it works for me... Do you get any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: No error messages :( well I will play around with it maybe I initialized at a wrong place...

Comment: I found my mistake! I indeed initialized the tooltip at the wrong place! It was too early, directly after the HTML Widget was added to the panel instead of after the Panel was added to the DOM widget! 
Thanks for explaining this!